# In java how I can delete Vowels are 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o' and 'u

Tags: java, regex, string

How can I delete vowels from a String except the vowel at the end of word?

For example  `"Please come to my party"`

To return `"Plse cme to my prty"`

Comment: now, this is a job for regular expressions if i ever saw one...

Comment: You better provide some more information like where you use it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
string.replaceAll("[aeiou]\\B", "")
```

Reads: Match all vowels (`[aeiou]`) that are not followed by an "end of word" (`\\B`). For more information read the Javadoc on [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Wouldn't `\B` suffice? It's potentially problematic, though, as that (and `\b`) indicates only a boundary between word and non-word characters. For most natural languages the regex definition of word characters is not sufficient, though.

Comment: Note that `\b` and `\B` are not characters, but zero-width anchors. They do not consume or match any characters.

Answer (score 3):

Turn the String into a char array.

Iterate through it.

Append each character to a StringBuilder, unless the next character is an alphabetic character.

Comment: That's so many lines of code, when you *could* use a regex... ;-)

Comment: Perfectly true. My bad. I spend so much time telling people "Don't use regexes when an `if` statement will do" or "*don't* parse HTML with regexes" that sometimes I overlook them when they *are* appropriate.