# Compare a char to an array of chars?

Tags: java, arrays

```
    package loopPractice;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class replaceVowels {
  static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    String originalString = s;

    char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};


    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      char c = s.charAt(i);
      if (c.equals(vowels[i])){
        String front = s.substring(0, i);
        String back = s.substring(i + 1);
        s = front + "" + back;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(originalString);
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

The job is to replace all vowels in a word, How can i replace every vowel using an array of vowels?

The question is: Write a method that returns a String that is a copy of a String parameter, but without any vowels

Comment: Are you married to the array-of-characters implementation?  There are much easier ways to remove certain characters from a `String`.

Comment: @Mohammad Where I'm from the married-to idiom is a fairly common way to ask someone for an estimation of their degree of attachment to something.  What does it mean to you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056861/in-java-how-i-can-delete-vowels-are-a-e-i-o-and-u dup?

Comment: @azurefrog i hear ya man .. i know what you meant.. found it funny in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the spirit of your question, you could write a new function that checks if an array contains a character:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    String originalString = s;

    char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (contains(c, vowels)) {
            String front = s.substring(0, i);
            String back = s.substring(i + 1);
            s = front + "" + back;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(originalString);
    System.out.println(s);
}

private static boolean contains(char c, char[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three big problems with this code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
  char c = s.charAt(i);
  if (c.equals(vowels[i])){
    String front = s.substring(0, i);
    String back = s.substring(i + 1);
    s = front + "" + back;
  }
}
```

First, you can't use `equals` on a `char`, since `char` is a primitive type.  Use `==`.

Second, you're not checking for vowels properly.  The above code compares the 0'th character of 's' to the 0'th character in the vowels array; that is, it compares it to `'a'` but not to any other vowel.  Similarly, it compares the character at index 1 to `'e'`, but not any other vowel, the character as 2 to `'i'`, etc.; when you get up to index 5, the program will throw an exception because `vowels` isn't that big.

The solution is that you need a *double loop* (or nested loop).  For each character in `s`, you will need to check it against *every* character in the `vowels` array (or at least until you hit a match).  So you'll need something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
  char c = s.charAt(i);
  boolean isAVowel = false;
  for (int j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++) {
      if (c == vowels[j]) {
         isAVowel = true;
         break;  // will leave the inner loop but not the outer loop
      }
      // I'll let you finish the rest
```

As @cptcactus demonstrated in his answer, moving the inner loop to a new method is a good way to implement this kind of solution.

The third problem is more subtle.  When you're looping through indexes in an array or string, and the loop removes elements from the array or string, you have to be **very careful** because the indexes will shift.  Suppose your code did approximately this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if [[[ s.charAt(i) is a vowel ]]] {
        [[[ remove the i'th character from s; ]]]
    }
}
```

Say `s` is `"air"`.  First `i` is set to 0, and `s.charAt(i)` is `'a'`.  This is a vowel, so we remove it.  This means `s` is now `"ir"`.  Then we loop back and set `i` to 1.  Now `s.charAt(i)` is `'r'` since it uses the new value of `s`, and it never looks at the vowel `'i'`.

A couple ways to work around that problem are:

- make sure `i` is not incremented if you remove a character from it (you could use `i--` which will cancel out the `i++`);
- go backwards through the indexes (i.e. start with `s.length()-1` and decrement) instead of forwards.

(There are other ways to solve this, by using the `replaceAll` method or a `Set<Character>`, but I'm assuming that this is a class and your purpose is to learn the basics of loops and such.)

Answer (score 0):

```
String.replaceAll("[aeiou](?!\\b)", "");
```

Reads: Match all vowels ([aeiou]) that are not followed ((?!...)) by an "end of word" (\b). For more information read the Javadoc on `java.util.regex.Pattern;`

even simpler would be this (equivalent but simpler) regex:

```
String.replaceAll("[aeiou]\\B", "");
```

Comment: The question says "using an array of vowels", so I am not sure this is an acceptable solution.